# Replace local repo with remote repo

Tags: git, repository, gerrit

I am going to give as much detail here as possible being that I am new and don't really know what I'm talking about.

I have a local repository from one git that I sync with. I am trying to replace that repository with a remote one from another git leaving NONE of the old repo behind. The one problem I seem to be having is pushing the changes after replacing the repo.

Here is the error:

> ```
> ! [remote rejected] HEAD -> 'refs' (no common ancestry)
> ```

**Method 1 I tried**

```
git add remote
git checkout remote
git push
```

**Method 2**

```
git add remote
git checkout remote
git reset <localBranch>
git push
```

Same error both ways. I don't think it'll make a difference, but I am trying to push to a gerrit for review.

Comment: "I have a local repository from one git that I sync with." Your use of the word "git" there makes no sense. Also, your error message implies that you're trying to push a commit tree that shares no common commits with the remote repo. Also, it would help if you clarify what you mean by "replace a local repo with a remote repo". If that is really what you're trying to accomplish, why couldn't you just delete the local repo and reclone it from the remote?

Comment: Told you I'm new so it's difficult to explain.

Basically, I have a project that resides here  https://github.com/vaniraosp/device_lge_g2-common

I am trying to replace that entire project/repo with the one that resides here:  https://github.com/bart452/device_lge_g2-common

I believe I tried cloning and got the same result.

Comment: Right, I did a reverse log and found that the two commit trees in the remotes don't share any commits whatsoever. You should just be able to force push the other commit tree, but if for some reason that doesn't work, why don't you just delete the original repo and push the other one up as the new source repo?

Comment: -f is force right? Where would I add that in? I believe I tried this as well by the way.

I have definitely deleted the original repo as well and tried pushing the other like you said, but I always run into the same error. Maybe I am using incorrect commands? How would you go about it?

Comment: @Cupcake I deleted the project, cloned the new one and tried pushing with -f, and still I get the no common ancestry message.

Comment: try the push with params: git push -f <remote> <local_branch>:<remote_branch>